# Minikube IP and Ingress Address are different. How to access services routed through Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, minikube, nginx-ingress

Minikube is deployed in EC2 Instance.
Kubernetes dashboard is deployed as cluster ip service in Minikube

Nginx-Ingress-Controller is deployed as NodePort service.
Ingress YAML file is below:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/$1"
  name: ingress-resource
spec:
  rules:
   - http:
      paths:
      - path: /kubedashboard
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: kubernetes-dashboard
            port:
              number: 443
```

Ingress address is:

[image]

Minikube IP is:

[image]

Minikube IP and Ingress Address are different. I did not mention any host in Ingress.yaml.

Ingress and Kubernetes dashboard are deployed in same namespace: kubernetes-dashboard.
How should I access kubernetes dashboard through Ingress?

I want to access with below :

```sh
curl https://localhost:NodePort/kubedashboard --insecure
```

or

```sh
curl https://MinikubeIP:NodePort/kubedashboard --insecure
```

or

```sh
curl https://EC2PublicIP:NodePort/kubedashboard --insecure
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need ingress, `ingress` is only used for ports 80 and 443, if you want to use node port to access dashboard, just set dashboard service type to NodePort.

Then you should be able to access with `curl https://localhost:NodePort/ --insecure`

```sh
kubectl patch service kubernetes-dashboard -n kubernetes-dashboard -p '{"spec": {"type": "NodePort"}}'
kubectl get service kubernetes-dashboard -n kubernetes-dashboard
```

If you really want to use ingress. Use below ingress, then you can access from https://localhost/kubedashboard/

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      rewrite ^(/kubedashboard)$ $1/ redirect;
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /kubedashboard(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: kubernetes-dashboard
            port:
              number: 443
```

Comment: Making kubernetes dashboard as nodeport service type works.. But I have few other microservices to be deployed.. So wanted to route everything through ingress instead of making all as nodeport services.

Comment: Added ingress for kubernetes-dashboard